# SQL- Creating a random varchar with length of 5

Tags: sql, database, db2

I need to create a `varchar(5)` value using SQL.  The string can only have letters and numbers, no special characters.  I have tried this (see below) but this did not work.

```
CHAR(ROUND(RAND() * 93 + 30, 0));
```

any idea of what is going on would be appreciated. The full code is listed below.

```
merge into fundtype as fund using (select fundtypnum, fundtype, country from table(values 
('JRLH5','$FOCA$01$$','USA'),
('YLHOV','$FOCA$02$$','AUS'),
('0MGJA','$FOCA$02$$','USA'),
('UK235','$FOCA$03$$','CAN'),
('HJP3C','$FOCA$03$$','USA')
))
as newfund (fundtypnum,fund_type,country) 
on (
 (fund.fund_type = newfund.fund_type and fund.country = newfund.country) or
 (fund.fundtypnum = newfund.fundtypnum)
)
when not matched then 
 insert (fundtypnum,fund_type,country) values (
    CHAR(ROUND(RAND() * 93 + 30, 0)),
    newfund.fund_type,
 newfund.country);
```

Comment: I suggest these steps.  1 - Create a random number > 1,000,000.  2. Convert it to hex.  3 - take the 5 rightmost characters.

Comment: Define "did not work".

Comment: Why do you think you need this?  What do you plan to do with the value?

Answer (score 1):

Change CHAR(ROUND(RAND() * 93 + 30, 0)) to

```
CONCAT(substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890',CEIL(RAND()*36),1),
    substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890',CEIL(RAND()*36),1),
    substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890',CEIL(RAND()*36),1),
    substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890',CEIL(RAND()*36),1),
    substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890',CEIL(RAND()*36),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Dan Bracuk's comment ... try something like this:

```
SELECT substring(reverse(sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CONVERT(varBINARY(8),
ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 1000000)))),1,5)
```